# Searching a discord server's history (contains millions of messages) without being rate-limited

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Ok, before I start off, I'd like to thank anyone who can help in advance.

Code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def index_levelups(ctx):
  checkchannel2 = get(ctx.guild.channels, name="check")
  checkmee6 = 871820545602232351
  if ctx.message.author.id == 425018496703791115:
    for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
      if channel.id != int(check):
        print("trying")
        messages = await channel.history(limit=None).flatten()
        lvl5 = "You have just advanced to level 5!"
        lvl10 = "You have just advanced to level 10!"
        lvl15 = "You have just advanced to level 15!"
        lvl20 = "You have just advanced to level 20!"
        lvl25 = "You have just advanced to level 25!"
        lvl30 = "You have just advanced to level 30!"
        lvl40 = "You have just advanced to level 40!"
        lvl50 = "You have just advanced to level 50!"
        lvl60 = "You have just advanced to level 60!"
        lvl70 = "You have just advanced to level 70!"
        bot = get(ctx.guild.roles, name="BOT")
        for msg in messages:
          if str(lvl70) in msg.content:
            if bot in msg.author.roles:
              await checkchannel2.send(msg.content)
          elif str(lvl60) in msg.content:
            if bot in msg.author.roles:
              await checkchannel2.send(msg.content)
          elif str(lvl50) in msg.content:
            if bot in msg.author.roles:
              await checkchannel2.send(msg.content)
          elif str(lvl40) in msg.content:
            if bot in msg.author.roles:
              await checkchannel2.send(msg.content)
          elif str(lvl30) in msg.content:
            if bot in msg.author.roles:
              await checkchannel2.send(msg.content)
          elif str(lvl25) in msg.content:
            if bot in msg.author.roles:
              await checkchannel2.send(msg.content)
          elif str(lvl20) in msg.content:
            if bot in msg.author.roles:
              await checkchannel2.send(msg.content)
          elif str(lvl15) in msg.content:
            if bot in msg.author.roles:
              await checkchannel2.send(msg.content)
          elif str(lvl10) in msg.content:
            if bot in msg.author.roles:
              await checkchannel2.send(msg.content)
          elif str(lvl5) in msg.content:
            if bot in msg.author.roles:
              await checkchannel2.send(msg.content)
```

This code stops working in the middle of the request. I assume because I'm trying to scout a server with around 20 channels, some containing up to a million messages for messages with a key-sentence in them, then taking that message and sending it to a specific channel in that server. Most likely not working because discord can't handle the amount of history requests // rate limits.

I need an alternative way to do this or some sort of fix that can still work fairly quickly and achieve the same goal. Thanks to anyone who gives feedback!

Comment: "*Ok, before I start off, I want to let anyone who can help me know that this is an extremely time sensitive project and I'd like to have a solution as quick as it can be given. I'm kind of in an urgent situation...*" [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: I’m simply letting you know how you can better conform to our posting guidelines here and increase your chances of getting an answer while also helping our goal of maintaining the content quality of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Okay, I edited my question to fit the format better. Your feedback will be noted from here out into the future :)

Comment: Why do you `.flatten()` the AsyncIterator returned from `channel.history` ?

Comment: I removed it a while ago and used async instead but it didnt make a difference